# Fatal error compiling: Unknown error trying to execute the external compiler: mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven

After mvn clean install am getting build failure with the following error. I have added the jdk path in environment variable, though i didnt find any solution.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project project-xmlbeans-eai: Fatal error compiling: Unknown error trying to execute the external compiler:
[ERROR] cmd.exe /X /C ""<C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\..\bin\javac.exe>" @C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler2487639668896206188arguments -J-Xmx2024m -J-Xms1024m"
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Can you post your POM? And the command you're using to launch Maven?

Comment: Also could you please provide what is your `JAVA_HOME` ?

Comment: I cant provide pom.xml file as it is project specific and confidential. JAVA_HOME, I have added in uservariables that is pointed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91